# Reading/writing POP3 data

Tags: c#, character-encoding, pop3

I'm receiving data from POP3 server and initially i used StreamWriter to write the data(as text) to a file on the disk, but with this approach certain characters cannot be decoded. Everything is ok if i use BinaryWriter and the BinaryWriter.Write(Byte[]) method. As far as i know StreamWriter writes text characters using specified encoding(certain bytes can be modified throughout the process), and BinaryWriter writes the original bytes to the file, is that right?

Comment: Hi. Just a side observation. It seems to me you are implementing a full blown POP3 client and MIME parser in C#. Might I ask you why you are not using some of the freely available ones? I am interested in this since I am currently maintaining one.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got bytes to start with and want to transfer them to a file, I'd suggest not using either `BinaryWriter` *or* `StreamWriter` - just use a `Stream` (e.g. `FileStream`). `BinaryWriter` is useful when you want to write primitives etc to a stream - but if you just want to dump a sequence of bytes, `Stream` does everything you want. You certainly *shouldn't* use `StreamWriter` to transfer opaque binary content; treat text as text, and binary data as binary data, and only translate between the two when you're sure of what you're doing (e.g. that the binary data is *actually* text in a particular encoding).

Answer (score 0):

can you show us how you are opening the StreamWriter specifying the encoding. I believe you should use the proper encoding in there, the one you are using now is probably wrong.

Comment: using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
{...
}

Comment: The problem is that the encoding is first know, when you are able to parse the POP3 content (properly a message). The Encoding used is described in the headers. Also, the encoding might be different for some parts of the message. A StreamWriter does not fit the purpose of writing POP3 message to disk.

Comment: That's correct, that's why I have voted +1 the answer of Jon Skeet above :)